# How to acces static dictionary from a class in MainWindow

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

I want to check if the first textbox matches for example "Tom" and the second textbox matches 1234. I can't figure out how to call the dictionary to the mainwindow. If anyone could help me out, let me know! :)

```
      public static class Wachtwoorden
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, string> dictionary
        = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
        {"Tom","1234" },
        {"Jan", "8765"},
        {"Piet","5678"},
        {"Dirk", "4321"}
            };
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a language tag.

Comment: @StephenNewell, that would be helpfull i guess haha, i"m sorry! Added it, C# :)

Comment: To access it from another class, you need to make it `public`.

Comment: It works haha, didn't thought of that. thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access it from any other class, you will have to make it **public**. ^^